# CCParticleSystemQuand not dealloced

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting, ccparticlesystem

I want to do a very simple thing but it's not working. I want to add some CCParticleSystemQuad in an NSMutableArray and delete them. Here is what I do :

```
int cpt = 0;
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (cpt = 0; cpt < 10; cpt++) {
    part = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"whiteExplosion.plist"];
    [myArray addObject:part];
}

NSLog(@"state of myArray : %@", myArray);

int cont = 0
for (cont = 0; cont < 10; cont++) {
    [myArray removeLastObject:cont];
}

NSLog(@"state of myArray : %@", myArray);
```

When I NSLog the first time I have this :

```
state of myArray : (
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x91ee380 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x84aca20 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x125136c0 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x125b0fc0 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x1250d480 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x1250fa50 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x9108840 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x9152b70 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x914fb80 | Tag = -1>",
    "<CCParticleSystemQuad = 0x9135470 | Tag = -1>"
)
```

The second time I have this :

```
state of myArray : (
)
```

So, as you can see my CCParticleSystemQuad have been removed. But, when I check in Instruments (allocations) they are still living (I have 20 still living [CCParticleSystemQuad allocMemory]) and still using memory for nothing. What am I missing ? BTW I use ARC.
I tried with (NSString *) object and it works fine... Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
[myArray removeLastObject:cont];
```

You're trying to delete an int from the array. You wanted to use removeLastObject (no params) or removeObjectAtIndex:

Your problem may be that you're not calling removeChild:particle

Answer (score 0):

You must remove it from its parent not only from array.

```
 [part removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

//to remove object from array

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
        [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

//remove only last object

```
        [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:([myArray count]-1)];
```

Comment: It does not work still have my objects living. Why do I have to call removeChild if I did not call addChild ? So, if I understand well, I always have to use [self addChild:part] and [self removeChild:part] when I want to add and remove a CCParticleSystemQuad from memory? What  is this working with NSString * object? Cause, I did not have to addChild my NSString to remove it from memory...

Comment: why do u create cocos2d particle object if not added to any layer/node   ? I thought u added..so suggested to remove. Ok LearnCocos2d already mentioned your mistake about adding int in to array..Happy coding.

Comment: Thx for you advice. But, why is it a mistake to stock it in an array?

Comment: I mean if it is not displayed in screen then why you create particle system? you told not used addChild, it means not displayed anywhere in screen :)

Comment: yeah, in fact, I create a lot of particle in a preload scene, because if I create them in my game scene the FPS dip down... When the user touches the screen a particle appears and I do not know how many times the users will tap on the screen. It could be 20, 100, 220 etc...

Comment: Thank you again, I close this post